# moving blender object in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

[Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rixs5.png)I am trying to make an object I have made in blender move in unity. I have used this script and it works with any object i put it on from unity, but when i try and put the script on my blender object it just stays still. My goal is to have the object scroll across the screen.

```
public class Player_Move : MonoBehaviour
```

{
public static int playerSpeed = 10;

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    gameObject.transform.Translate(Vector3.right * playerSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post a picture of the hierarchy of your blender object within Unity?  There's very little that could be wrong with your script from what you've shown.  Maybe there's something wrong with the hierarchy.

Comment: hello Alex. I have posted a pic of the hierarchy

Comment: Is the object maybe set as static or does it have animations?

Comment: yes the object has an animation on it

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you add a script as component into `gameObject`?
2. Make sure you set settings when you export your gameObject from Blender. [reference](https://gamedevacademy.org/how-to-import-blender-models-into-unity-your-one-stop-guide/)
3. If still not working please share Inspector table of gameObject as screenshot.